# Invalid null value for partition key part url

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql3, spark-cassandra-connector

I have the following code which is trying to join 2 cassandra tables in spark.

```
 val imageKeywords = sc.cassandraTable[ImageMetadata]("images", "metadata")
 val imageAndPageKeywords = imageKeywords
  .joinWithCassandraTable[PagesMetadata]("pages2", "metadata")
  .on(SomeColumns("tid", "url" as "pu"))
```

The case classes I am using to map data are as below

```
case class ImageMetadata(tid: String, iu: String, pu: Option[String],
mk: List[String], fk: List[String], ak: List[String], ipk: List[String], pk: List[String], ik: List[String], ck: List[String])

case class PagesMetadata(tid: String, url: String, pk: List[String], uk: List[String], hk: List[String], ok: List[String], tc: List[String])
```

I get an error when I try to do some operations like below

```
imageAndPageKeywords.collect.toList.sortBy(_._1.tid).take(10).foreach(println)
```

error stacktrace -

> Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid null value for partition key part url
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:103)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:140)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:293)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.onSet(RequestHandler.java:455)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Connection.java:734)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>       at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.java:36)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
>       at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.messageReceived(IdleStateHandler.java:294)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
>       at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
>       at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
>       at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
>       at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
>       at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
>       at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
>       ... 3 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, the exception tells you that it cannot perform the join because the column used to join **ImageMetadata** with **PagesMetadata** are null.

In your case, some *url* (pu) values in **ImageMetadata** are null.

What is strange is that you define the **PagesMetadata** with *url* nullable (Option[String]) and it seems that it is part of the table's primary key

One solution to make it work would be:

```
val imageAndPageKeywords = imageKeywords
  .filter(im -> im.pu.isDefined)
  .joinWithCassandraTable[PagesMetadata]("pages2", "metadata")
  .on(SomeColumns("tid", "url" as "pu"))
```

Comment: Is there a way I can make the join work ? I was kind of trying to see if Option(String) for url would resolve my issue.

Comment: Here is what I am doing keeping your suggestion in mind. 

    `val imageKeywords = sc.cassandraTable[ImageMetadata]("images", "metadata")`
`val pageKeywordsByTidUrl = imageKeywords.joinWithCassandraTable[PagesMetadata]("pages2", "metadata")
    .on(SomeColumns("tid", "url" as "pu"))
    .filter(f=> f._1.pu.isDefined).keyBy{ x => Joinkey(x._1.tid, x._1.iu) }`
But still the same error

Comment: Put the filter BEFORE the join !